# Using range() function as parameter in scipy.stats hypergeom.pmf()

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, scipy

I'm working on a program which calculates an error value by generating a list of PMFs of a hypergeometric distribution over a range of values, computing the pairwise product of this list and another list, normalizing the list using a common denominator, then summing a portion of the list.

The code has been working well on my Windows laptop (running Python 3.7.1 on Anaconda) and on an Ubuntu environment (Python 3.6.7), but will not run on a new Windows Desktop (running Python 3.7.3). I have already looked in the scipy documentation but there is not much detail about what the hypergeom.pmf function can handle as parameters. I believe it has something to do with the new environment and maybe the version of Python installed.

```
from scipy.stats import hypergeom as hg

def get_error(self, stop: int, audit: int) -> float:
        # Get posterior distribution
        posterior = hg.pmf(stop, self.total_votes, range(0, self.total_votes+1), audit)
        posterior = [posterior[i]*self.prior[i] for i in range(len(posterior))]
        posterior /= sum(posterior)

        return sum(posterior[range(self.total_votes//2 + 1)])
```

Usually, `posterior = hg.pmf(stop, self.total_votes, range(0, self.total_votes+1), audit)` will return a list of PMFs and the function will then return a float between 0 and 1. When running on the new machine, the program will not continue and gives the following error message:

```
...
    test_error = self.get_error(test_stop, audit_size)
  File "C:\...\filename.py", line 77, in get_error
    posterior = hg.pmf(stop, self.total_votes, list(range(0, self.total_votes+1)), audit)
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py", line 2942, in pmf
    _a, _b = self._get_support(*args)
  File "C:..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_discrete_distns.py", line 355, in _get_support
    return np.maximum(N-(M-n), 0), np.minimum(n, N)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'
```

It seems the hypergeom.pmf() function no longer accepts range() as a parameter, but the code works perfectly on two other environments. Could there be an update or outdated package on the new machine which was not installed/upgraded correctly when setting up the new environment?

Comment: Does `list(range(...))` work any better? (though that's more of a 2.7 vs 3.x issue.)

Comment: What is the scipy version on each of the machines?  You can check with `import scipy; print('scipy.__version__')`

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser The code works in both of these environments: Windows machine (scipy 1.1.0) and the Ubuntu system (scipy 1.2.1). The new Windows desktop which gives the error has scipy 1.3.0 (which I believe is the most recent version).